# Understanding insertChild – atIndex?

Tags: swift, ios8, sprite-kit

how do i add a couple of SKShapeNode to my SpriteKit Scene. 
The latest "newEnemy" should always be placed to the back of my scene.

How do i get the backgroundIndex for insertChild()?

```
let backgroundIndex:Int = ???
self.insertChild(newEnemy, atIndex: backgroundIndex)
```

Comment: Is your question how to get the index of your background node? The question title seems to indicate one thing, but your code has ??? indicating you want to find the index of your background in relation to the nodeTree.

Comment: I believe that `insertChild:atIndex` is bugged and doesn't work in regards to rendering unless it's been fixed recently. Also, handling rendering order with zPosition is best practice. If you look in default project the `ignoresSiblingOrder` property is set to `true`, and is commented as an optimization. With that property set to true, you are just rearranging indexes in the children array, not specifying render order.